# Set OneDrive Files to Available Online Only in Win7

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive seems to be syncronizing files to my Windows 7 machine which I don't want it to do because of HDD space considerations.  So for instance, the video files should not consume space on my Win7 machine so I want to make the files Available Online Only.  That options is available on my Win8.1 machine but does not appear to be available on my Win7 machine. How can I configure OneDrive to make such files only available online and not consume storage on my local Win7 machine?

Comment: What you want to do, isn't a feature, of the Windows 7 OneDrive client.

Comment: I don't have this on a W7 PC but it is certainly possible on W8 and I'd be surprised if they are different clients. Settings has a button.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has a specific feature for OneDrive (available only only) that will not be supported going forward. Microsoft has stated it is a confusing feature and will offer OneDrive as sync software. The best way to configure OneDrive is to set up selective sync. You select a folder you do not want to sync to your computer(s). You can then upload files you only want on OneDrive into that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on OneDrive icon and go to

> Settings > Account tab > Choose folders

there you can select the folders you want to be synced